# Irreducibility of a polynomial over rationals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am given the polynomial $x^4+1$ and I am asked to prove that it is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$. I was just wondering if it is enough to show that $x^4+1$ does not contain a root in $\mathbb Q$ and therefore it is not irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$?

Comment: It could factor as the product of two quadratic polynomials.

Comment: yes. That is true. It is reducible in $Q(\sqrt{2})[x]$. But my question is asking to prove it is irreducible in $Q[x]$

Comment: I know that your question is asking to prove that it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, but irreducible means: Whenever you write it as the product of two polynomials $f\cdot g$ then either $f$ or $g$ is a unit, which in this case means that it is a number in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: You have proved that it is not possible to factor it as a linear factor times a cubic factor.

Comment: Thank you @DanielMontealegre

Answer (score 2):

No that is not enough.  That would only show that it has no linear factors.  As Daniel pointed out, it could factor as a product of two quadratic polynomials.  You could try a couple of approaches:

1) Use the factorization of this polynomial over $\mathbb{C}$ to conclude that it cannot factor over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Factor it completely over $\mathbb{C}$ and show that no product of these factors (other than the product of all four of them) lies in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

2) Make a change of variables and try to apply the Eisenstein Criterion.

Comment: Nice answer. You could, in addition, apply Gauss' lemma that states that irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same as irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$. We know it has no linear factors, so suppose it has quadratic factors $(X^2+aX\pm1)(X^2+b\pm1), \dots$

Comment: I see what you are saying. I have already showed that if it were reducible then it is either equal to the product of a polynomial of degree 3 and one of degree 1 both of which are not units of $Q[x]$. or it is the product of two degree two polynomials. Both cases gave me a contradiction. So therefore it must be the case that it is irreducible. I was also given to show that $x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1$ was irreducible in $Q(\sqrt{2})[x]$. In this case, my question will show that it is irreducible if it does not have a root in $Q(\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: Yes, a polynomial of degree three or less is reducible if and only if it has a root.

Answer (score 0):

No, showing that a polynomial does not have a root does not prove the irreducibility of the polynomial (both in general, and in the case you are considering). If the polynomial were of degree less than $4$, then showing it has no root does prove it is irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to show that it does not contain a root, because it could also factor as the product of two quadratics. Ab absurdo say $f\cdot g$ are quadratics that multiply to $x^4+1$. Then, you can assume that both $f$ and $g$ are monic (Why?), then consider $f(x)=x^2+ax+b$ and $g(x)=x^2+cx+d$, and if you multiply them you get a system of equations. If you try to solve this system you should get a contradiction.

Comment: This is an alternate solution from the ones that Alistair is proposing. His are more advance whereas mine is tedious but straight forward.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Thank you! I was just hoping it would be as easy as showing it had no roots in $Q$. Just to make things shorter. But I now know that this is only the case for polynomials of degree less than 4.

Answer (score 0):

Note that pairing the complex conjugate roots of $x^4+1$ gives $$x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)(x-\sqrt2x+1)$$ but this is not a factorisation into polynomials with rational coefficients (and other pairings of the roots do not even give a factorisation over $\mathbb R$).